# PHP: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Tags: php, preg-match, warnings

I`m making a php file to search images in a directory introducing the name, but the function preg_match returns me this error: "Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash". The code is this:

```
<?php
$ruta='fotos'; 
// Usamos dir 
$dir=dir($ruta);     
// Archivo a Buscar 

$busqueda=$_POST['busqueda'] ;
$buscar = $busqueda; 

// Recorremos los Archivos del Directorio 
while ($elemento = $dir->read()) 
{     
     // Evitamos el . y ... 
    if ( ($elemento != '.') and ($elemento != '..')) 
    { 
        // Vemos si Existe el Archivo 
        if (preg_match($buscar, $elemento) AND is_file($ruta.$elemento)  ) 
        { 
            echo " Archivo : $elemento <br>"; 
        } 


    }       
}     
?>
```

It gives me the warning for each iteration in the loop. I`ve trying to fix it but I can`t. Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Change `$buscar = "arica";` to `$buscar = "#arica#";`

Comment: Show how you tried to fix it, that saves us all trying the same thing :)

Comment: [Y U NO USE THE SEARCH BAR](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[preg-match]+Delimiter+must+not+be+alphanumeric+or+backslash)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove that, that was only a test. The real search is done with:
<pre><code>
$busqueda=$_POST['busqueda'] ;
$buscar = $busqueda;
</code></pre>

Comment: @Metalaria that doesn't matter, you just need to add delimiters. Welcome to the world of regex :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do enough research on this question.

```
$buscar = "arica";
```

is your pattern I guess. I don't see any regex here but anway it needs to have delimiter.

[From php manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and tildes (~). The following are all examples of valid delimited patterns.

So you need to use one of delimiters for example

```
$buscar = "/arica/";
```

however in your case remove preg_match() and use simply

```
$buscar == $elemento
```

It will do the same.

Morover, you should consider using [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php). With it you could change your code to

```
$ruta='fotos'; 
$busqueda=$_POST['busqueda'] 
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator($ruta);
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
  if ($fileinfo->isFile() && $fileinfo->getFileName() == $busqueda) {
       echo " Archivo : $elemento <br>"; // here can be added 'break' I guess there is only 1 file with name you search for.
  }
}
```

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve but maybe you should just use `file_exists();`

Answer (score 0):

The error is cause by `preg_match($buscar, $elemento)`. That call succeeds or fails depending on what the value of `$buscar` is. However, `$buscar` comes from the user, because of

```
$busqueda=$_POST['busqueda'] ;
$buscar = $busqueda;
```

First of all, not many users are able to formulate regular expressions, so asking a user for a regular expression is likely not a good idea. I don't know if you even intended to, because the variable `$buscar` is previously defined as `$buscar = "arica"` (it's not a good idea to reuse the same variable for different purposes, it confuses the developers.)

Secondly, strings that you pass to `preg_match()` as pattern must contain a *delimiter*. I don't know whether the `a` in `$buscar = "arica"` is a valid delimiter, it certainly is an unusual one (usually, `/` is chosen as delimiter, but others work as well). So it should be

```
$buscar = "/arica/";
```

but note that `/arica/` won't be used as regular expression anway, because of what I said earlier.